# Run a deployed JBoss Fuse Integration application

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse

I exported a Fuse Integration project as a jar file and deployed it to a remote server. Like so:

#### Start server for all IPs

`/root/EAP-7.1.0/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0`

#### start the management cli

`/root/EAP-7.1.0/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect`

#### deploy

`deploy /home/ec2-user/fuseToolingTutorial.jar`

When I access the EAP Admin platform (The console that's on port 9990 by default), I'm able to see that the file was in fact deployed, but I don't see any way to run the project.

If there's documentation on how to actually run Fuse applications deployed on EAP please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to follow the official Installation Guide:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_fuse/7.0/html-single/installing_on_jboss_eap/

Quick answer is you need to install [the Fuse 7 on EAP installer](https://developers.redhat.com/download-manager/file/fuse-eap-installer-7.0.0.fuse-000085-redhat-1.jar) before deploying your Fuse application jars as follows:

```
cd $EAP_HOME
java -jar fuse-eap-installer-7.0.0.fuse-000085-redhat-1.jar
```